# passing error code in exception that has enum object

Tags: java, enums

I am new to java and from c++ background.

I am trying the following:

```
public myErrors {

  enum errorTypeOne {

      PARAM(0, "something"),
      PARAM1(1, "SOMETHING");

      errorTypeOne(int errval, String str)
      {
          this.value = errVal;
          this.errorStr = str;
      }

      public int getValue()
      {
           return this.value;
      }
      public String getDesc()
      {
          return this.errorStr;
      }
      public errorTypeOne getErrorTypeOneFor(int x)
      {
              for(errorTypeOne eCode : values()) 
              {
                     if( eCode.value == x ) 
                       return eCode;
              }

             return null;
      }
}


       private int value;
       private String errorStr;

 }
}
```

so far so good. Now In my code i throw a exception which encapsulates an object for 'errorTypeOne'.

Now user of my java class can access this with try catch block

```
try {
  // something that throws myException.

} 
catch ( MyException ex )
{
   if ( ex.errType  == myErrors.errorTypeOne.PARAM )
    {
      // do something..
      // print -> ex.errType.getDesc()
    }
   if ( ex.errType == myErrors.errorTypeOne.PARAM1 )
    {
        // do something...
        // print -> ex.errType.getDesc()
    }
}
```

**Question:**

1)  MY Question is is this 'if' condition is valid to check ?

2)  is it the right approach to introduce getErrorTypeOneFor(int x) API

Please advise, and let me know where i overlooked?.